# Custom require function. How run modules and load another module in the module?

Tags: javascript, module, require

I creating custom require.

How can I init modules with require in module, if require('module') not inited yet.

[Demo with error](https://playcode.io/require?tabs=runtime.js&utils.js&player.js&output) (if utils.js before player.js, then work. **Error in console**.)

**require**

```
var __modules = []
function require() {
  return __modules[0].exports
}
```

**module first**

```
(function() {

  var module = {}
  module.exports = {}

  // Begin module

  var beep = require('beep')
  beep() // it'll undefined, because this module inited first... But need require without modules order.

  // End module

}())
```

**module beep**

```
(function() {

  var module = {}
  module.exports = {}

  // Begin module
  function beep() {
    console.log("beep")
  }

  module.exports = beep
  // End module

  __modules.push( module )

}())
```